# Error opening shared document via CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, cloudkit

CloudKit sharing was introduced this year and I'm trying to implement it.

I'm using the `UICloudSharingController` and I'm saving the share and its root record in the completion handler which succeeds. However, when I share the link (e.g. via iMessage) and open it on another device (different iCloud account, same build), it shows the following error:

> Couldn't open "Share"
>
> You need a newer version of `APPNAME`to open this, but the required version couldn't be found in the App Store. If you're not sure which version to use, check with the owner.

As this is a new app, it is of course not in the App Store. I need to test sharing first (Chicken or the egg?), so anyone knows how to test CloudKit sharing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out, I was missing the

`<key>CKSharingSupported</key>
<true/>`

entry in my `Info.plist`. This resolved the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot was facing the same problem

Comment: After 5 hours... Thanks a lot!! I'm surprised no one tutorial I've read said nothing about this!